# Interfacing TRRS headphone to Arduino Uno

Tags: analogread, audio, analog-sampling

I have been working in a Arduino project lately which requires human voice input to Arduino with some processing Arduino need to perform specific task. Simple sampling of incoming signal and calculating average amplitude from it nothing complex.

My problem is I have tried using electret microphone to receive human voice input but failed since the Elec Mic is not sensitive to detect the voice even though i hooked up with LM386 amplifier circuit. So that option is out of the picture. Then i intend to use Android mobile headphones (TRRS) to receive the human voice which will provide great sensitivity for our voice.

Starting through simple internet searches i bought a product [3.5mm breakout module from Ebay](http://www.ebay.in/itm/M314-3-5mm-Jack-Breakout-Board-Headset-Audio-Stereo-Socket-Extension-Module-DIY-/111937904531?). But am unsure of how to connect them to Arduino. Different sources in internet giving different information i couldn't figure out how to connect the headphone to arduino and read it's Mic output from headphone.

Seeing the pin out of TRRS headphones 
[image: TRRS headphone jack connection]
i can't understand how could i possibly power my headphones with only GND pin available. I tried several wiring connections given in the internet to read the Mic output of my headphones through Analog pin A0 of Arduino but no luck so far. So my question is

**1) How do i power the TRRS headphone using Arduino?


2) How can i read the MIC output of my headphone using Arduino? Is it even possible?

3) I have read somewhere the audio out from headphones will be of FSK modulated is it true?**

Any help will be much appreciated. Please do provide if you have any links that might answer my questions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No.... Just that: no.

Comment: You were seriously ripped off with that breakout. That's about 10p worth of components they sold you for about £4.

Comment: You "power" the left and right channels of the headphones the same way you "power" a pair of speakers: send an audio-frequency signal of sufficient amplitude to them. This is, for example, what a headphone amplifier or the audio amplifier in your stereo system does.

Comment: Welcome to Arduino SE.  You can take the tour at https://arduino.stackexchange.com/Tour

Comment: @Majenko That's a real shame and i regret for buying it.

Comment: @Curt J. Sampson Thanks for that :) but i need to receive signal from Mic part of my headphone to my Arduino pin and how do i do it? Should i connect a 10k resistor in series with "Sleeve" pin and pull it high to 5v rail like the way we use the electret microphones in a circuit?    That's the part am having trouble with exactly.

Comment: You use whatever technique is appropriate for the microphone connected to the sleeve pin, which is the same technique you'd use for that mic. when connected via something other than TRRS. I think you really want to ask a new question describing the mic. you're using (as opposed to the cable between the mic. and Arduino) and asking how to hook that up.

Comment: @CurtJ.Sampson Identifying  the Microphone can be a problem. Am using my old Samsung mobile headphone for feeding the voice input to my project. I am not sure Mic used can be identified in it. Thoughts please?

Comment: Seems the question then might be, "given a typical headset/mic of the sort used on PCs and mobile phones with a TRRS jack, how can I use the mic as input to an Ardunio to do _______?"

Comment: @Curt J Sampson Yeah that makes more sense will post a new question as you suggested

Answer (score 1):

TRRS relates to the style of the jack plug used: Tip Ring Ring Sleeve. You still need to amplify the signal with a microphone preamp the same as your electret (in fact it will be an electret in there anyway).

And then the Arduino cannot process human speech. You may be able to use [a voice recognition module](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13316) to get it to respond to specific commands, but the Arduino by itself has no hope of even thinking about it.

Comment: Check PID library for signal processing possibilities

Comment: @mico How on earth can the PID library process audio?

Comment: I meant to tell some basic signal processing library, first I found was PID. It did not do what I wanted on closer look. Supposedly there is some low pass filtering, noise reduction and or echo controls available? Or are they all circuits on this scale? Not libraries?

Comment: @mico The Arduino lacks the resources to do much in the way of audio processing. The quantity of data and speed of processing required is too much. You can do low-pass filtering (averaging) on small sample sets (a few hundreds of samples - fractions of a second), and just about run an integer FFT on a similarly tiny sample set. Anything like voice recognition is impossible without dedicated hardware.

Comment: I missed the need for recognizing voice. Signal sampling can maybe detect sound level in general, quite much not more, so it is not good fit.

Comment: @Majenko I described it incorrectly, i didn't want to do complex signal processesing with the input signal. To be more clear my project is intended for fun purpose only so nothing critical. Am looking to sample the input signal from MIC and then want to determine the average amplitude of the samples no big deal ( I believe). But am stuck at getting the input from the headphone mic to the Arduino, to cut my question short what exactly i need to connect to the "Sleeve" part of my this TRRS module to get the output? Any suggestions please

Comment: @FrankDonald You need a microphone preamp then. With that you need a 50% Vcc DC offset imposed on the signal for the ADC to read it properly.  You can build your own, there's plenty of schematics on google. Or you can probably buy one.

Comment: @Majenko Now that can be a start. I will look for preamp circuits and build one for my headphones. But again the question stands how to connect it to the sleeve pin and my headphones will be powered? thoughts? Edited the question with image explaining my problem, kindly take a look

Comment: You don't power it at all. The microphone forms part of a circuit and that circuit is powered.

Comment: @Majenko Seems like i got some idea about that. Let me try it out and see check if it works

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me as if your project is really more about what you do with the audio once you're sampling it into the Arduino and this whole "how do I get a usable signal out of a microphone" thing is not your main interest. In that case, I suggest just going with something like [this MEMS microphone breakout board](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9868) which includes the microphone and all the circuitry necessary to get a proper signal to an analog input on the Arduino.

Comment: Looks like pretty thing to use for my project will consider buying it. But before that let me try again with my headphones with all suggestions. Am trying to make it look like more of DIY setup so hoping my headphone setup should work